# Depth Calibration Target

Tags: kinect, camera-calibration, kinect-sdk

I am trying to gather as much resources as possible regarding to depth calibration of Kinect camera.

One question which is not that trivial for me is the following:

What kind of calibration target should be used with Microsoft Kinect camera.

I'm thinking of having kind of checker-board based pattern, but not sure whether the depth sensor would be able to detect it. Am i right?

Maybe high precision 3-D objects would be more beneficial for calibration of the depth camera?

Thank you very much!

P.S Please consider the fact that i am going to use only depth sensor on Kinect and not RGB sensor, as i mentioned.

Comment: The Kinect does not need to be calibrated and does not have a mechanism to really do so.  What is your ultimate goal that makes you want to calibrate the camera?

Comment: My ultimate goal is the calibration of depth camera.

In more details: Let's say i am using multiple Kinects within the scene. So I need to calibrate them and find the extrinsic parameters (translation and rotation w.r.t world coordinate system). Once I have that information, i can reconstruct the scene at highest level of accuracy.

Comment: If I understand, you're looking to recognize where the Kinects are positioned relative the scene, or each other?  Have you looked at the acceleration within the Kinect?  That will give you translation and rotation information.  But to get relative position to each other you'd want to use a cube (or other 3D shape) at a known point.  A flat panel will not help for depth information.

Comment: What are you trying to align? The point cloud data or the rgb images? What some projects have successfully done is to make a "checkerboard" out of white paper squares and tinfoil squares, which will show up as a checkerboard in the depth stream. In a 3d calibration setup I helped developed we did however use a distinct thin 2D asymmetrical panel which we detect within the individual point clouds and use to figure out the camera viewpoints.